# Export Highcharts to PDF - IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, svg, highcharts

I have my highcharts code, where i want to export highcharts to PDF using **IE9** only.

In my code the chart svg is getting rendered, but does nothing after that, I get the console.log output till this line in the code `LOG 2 : return back`, after that the page becomes still.

I cannot understand if there is any problem with the imported js or with the code.
Can anyone please help me figure out the problem.

My code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />
    <title>MyChart></title>

<!-- Dependencies -->   
<script src="//a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside/bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="//a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside/bower_components/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function()
             {
                getData();
            });

            function getData() {

                var options = {
                    chart : {
                        renderTo : 'container',
                        type:'area'
                    },
                    xAxis : {
                        categories : []
                    },

                    yAxis : [ {
                        title : {
                            text : 'Values'
                            }
                        }],

                    exporting: {
                        enabled : true,
                         type: 'application/pdf'
                            },
                    series : []
                };

                //jquery to populate the series
                $.get(url, function(xml) {
                    var $xml = $(xml);
                    $xml.find('category dates').each(
                            function(i, category) {
                                options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
                            });
                    $xml.find('types Series').each(
                            function(i,series){
                                var seriesOptions = {
                                        name : $(series).find('name').text(),
                                        data : [],
                                        type : 'area',
                                    };
                                $(series).find('date point').each(
                                    function(i,point){
                                        seriesOptions.data.push(parseInt($(point).text()));
                                    });
                                    options.series.push(seriesOptions);
                            });
                    myChart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });

                // PDF starts
                Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts) {
                    var svgArr = [],
                    top = 0,
                    width = 0;

                $.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
                    var svg = chart.getSVG();
                    svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
                    svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

                    top += chart.chartHeight;
                    width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

                    svgArr.push(svg);
                });

                console.log(" LOG 1 : "+'<svg height="'+ top +'" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>');
                return '<svg height="'+ top +'" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
            };
            Highcharts.exportCharts = function(charts, options) {

                options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

                Highcharts.post(options.url, {
                    filename: options.filename || 'Pulse_Chart',
                    type: options.type,
                    width: options.width,
                    svg: Highcharts.getSVG(charts)
                });
                console.log("LOG 2 : return back");
            };

            $('#export').click(function() {
                Highcharts.exportCharts([myChart], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            });

            }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <img src="pdf.bmp" id="export"/>
    <div id="container" class="myChart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Logs : 
[image]

Comment: Have you checked or asked in http://forum.highcharts.com/ ?

Comment: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/export-highcharts-to-pdf-ie9-t35481/

Comment: Since you have not provided data, then I have used an exemplary series array with 2 series with exemplary data. After clicking on image chart is being downloaded in IE9 (just tested) - example: http://jsfiddle.net/u897LbaL/1/. So maybe there is a problem with data? Could you update the example to show the issue? Also, no need to load exporting module twice, especially when current version of exporting module is not compatible with other files that you are using (they are older versions).

Comment: I removed the older version of js like you said. Actually I read the data from an xml file, using jquery. I dont think there is problem with the data, since i get the chart correctly. I even get the logs as you get in the above fiddle example. I neither get any errors nor warnings with my code above. After the chart getting rendered, i do not get the pop up for opening the chart,in IE9. I have been stuck with this for weeks. Could you please help?

Comment: In your fiddle i have attached my full logs as comments in the end, 
fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/w9bdu3dg/  . I just get this, no issues or warnings